# IOS C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer (Not using strings)

Tags: c++

I included the "not using strings" part in the title because when I was searching to find an answer on here I saw this problem a lot but it was with people using strings and getting chars mixed up. This is not my issue.

Trying to call an element of a 2D vector and see if it equals a certain number. I'm getting the comparison between pointer/integer error and I don't understand why. Here's my code, any help would be really appreciated.

```
bool UsedInRow(vector< vector<int> > vec(int n, vector<int> (int n)), int row, int num)
{

  int n;

  for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
  {
     if (vec[row][col] == num)
     {
         return true;
     }
  }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
bool UsedInRow(const vector< vector<int> >& vec, int row, int num) { ... }
```

The expression you used `vector< vector<int> > vec(int n, vector<int> (int n))` is actually a function pointer.

Comment: How can you be sure it's not *supposed* to be a function pointer? If it should be a vector, why is the nested parameter list there in the first place? (We won't know the answer until the OP explains.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: He uses `vec` like a 2D array and not like a function pointer. So I applied Occam's razor.

Comment: And you may well be right -- but surely the `(int n, vector<int> (int n))` wasn't just a random typo. The code contains a quite complicated and perfectly valid declaration of a function that takes a function pointer argument, where the pointed-to function itself takes another function pointer argument. There's something else going on here (and I have no idea what).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler thinks that you are passing a function pointer.

Instead, pass the `vector` by reference:

```
bool UsedInRow(vector< vector<int> > &vec, int row, int num)
```

Comment: I would not call that *vexing parse*, in this particular case it is **obviously** a function signature being passed!! Most vexing parse is usually referred to the case where a declaration can be parsed as either a variable or function declaration and the latter is preferred in the language, but there is no such ambiguity here

Comment: What's vexing is there's a function being passed as an argument, but this is completely ignored in the comparison code, where it's treated as if a reference was passed in. Re-creating the `vec` structure through each iteration of the loop seems wrong, whereas receiving a pre-existing `vec` makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out, `vec` is a function pointer, not a vector.

You're being advised to change `vec` to a vector, but it's not clear that that's the right solution. There's no ambiguity in your declaration; `vec` is defined as a parameter of function pointer type.

If that's what you intended, you need to replace the reference to `vec` inside the function with a function call. For example, you might change

```
if (vec[row][col] == num)
```

to

```
if ((vec(42, something))[row][col] == num)
```

where `something` would itself have to be a function pointer, pointing to a function that takes an `int` argument and returns a `vector<int>` result.

The declaration of your `UsedInRow` function is quite complicated, and I can't tell how it's intended to be used.

If `vec` really should be just a vector, then you can make it one by deleting the `(int n, vector<int> (int n))` part of the parameter declaration -- but then I'd have to wonder why you wrote it in the first place.

For a definitive answer, you'd need to explain to us what your `UsedInRow` function is supposed to do.